# Generating a pattern to be matched

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I am dealing with brackets `br[arg1, arg2, ...]`, having a sequence of positive integers (labels) as argument. Brackets are totally antisymmetric, hence it is important - when reordering labels - to keep track of the sign of the permutation.

I want to write a very simple sorting function, such that, given an arbitrary expression involving several brackets, reorders their arguments putting a prescribed subset of labels in front.

I have a first function, *sort*, that works just fine when the subset of distinguished labels has length 2.

```
sort[expr_, lab_List] := Block[{},

 expr //. {br[a1___, lab[[1]], a2___, lab[[2]], a3___] :> 
           Signature[{a1, lab[[1]], a2, lab[[2]], a3}]*Signature[Join[{lab[[1]], lab[[2]]}, { a1, a2, a3}]]*
           br @@ Join[{lab[[1]], lab[[2]]}, {a1, a2, a3}]}
]
```

As an example, consider

```
ex = br[1, 5, 7, 8, 9] br[3, 1, 5, 7, 8] br[3, 1, 4, 5] + br[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5] br[1, 3, 5] br[1, 7, 8, 5, 3]
sort[ex, {1, 5}]
```

> ```
> Out[3]= -br[1, 5, 3, 4] br[1, 5, 3, 7, 8] br[1, 5, 7, 8, 9] + br[1, 5, 3] br[1, 5, 7, 8, 3] br[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6]
> ```

Then I tried to generalize it, to allow subset of arbitrary length to be sorted in front of every argument and this is what I came up with.

```
genSort[expr_, lab_List] := Block[{otherLabels},

 otherLabels = Table[ToExpression@StringJoin["a", ToString[i]], {i, 1, Length[lab] + 1}];

 expr //. {br @@ Riffle[(Pattern[#, ___] & /@ otherLabels), lab] :> 
           Signature[Riffle[otherLabels, lab]]*Signature[Join[lab, otherLabels]]*
           br @@ Join[lab, otherLabels]}
]
```

Now when I try to use this more general version of the function on the previous example, I get

```
ex = br[1, 5, 7, 8, 9] br[3, 1, 5, 7, 8] br[3, 1, 4, 5] + br[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5] br[1, 3, 5] br[1, 7, 8, 5, 3]
genSort[ex, {1, 5}]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[44]:= ReplaceRepeated::rrlim: Exiting after br[3,1,4,5] br[1,5,7,8,9] br[3,1,5,7,8]+br[1,3,5] br[1,7,8,5,3] br[2,3,4,1,6,5] scanned 65536 times.
> Out[4]= 2 br[1, 5, a1, a2, a3]^3
> ```

Now, beside the warning about the `ReplaceRepeated`, obviously the problem is that I am not able to convince *Mathematica* to identify the `a1,a2,...` with appropriate (possibly empty) sequences of labels, as it was seamlessly doing with the more specific function above.
**I understand that *Mathematica* is just using the labels `a1, a2, ...` ignoring the pattern matching construct, but I still believe that the implementation is correct in spirit. Is there a way to save it, or is it doomed?** (I also tried to use some `Evaluate` command here and there, it doesn't seem to change anything.)

On a separate note, I created the list of `a`-indices with a rather cumbersome construct. However, this was the only one I could think of which could allow to create an *a priori* unspecified number of objects and to append some blanks to them to define a pattern (neither `a[i]`, nor `Subscript[a,i]` would do, of course). **Is there a better way out?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the issue in the code**

`RuleDelayed` evaluates its left-hand side but not its right-hand side. In the expression

```
br @@ Riffle[(Pattern[#, ___] & /@ otherLabels), lab] :> 
    Signature[Riffle[otherLabels, lab]] *
    Signature[Join[lab, otherLabels]] *
    br @@ Join[lab, otherLabels]
```

the pattern is correctly constructed in the left-hand side and will be of the form

```
br[a1___, lab[[1]], a2___, lab[[2]], ..., lab[[n - 1]], an___]
```

with the `lab[[i]]` replaced by their corresponding values.

The right-hand side, since not evaluated, does not contain the symbols `a1`, `a2`, ..., `an` at the time of the construction of the rule; it contains instead the unevaluated symbol `otherLabels`. This means that the `ai` hidden in `otherLabels` are not bound to their pattern counterpart on the left-hand side.

Specifically, when an expression matches the pattern given in the left-hand side, the subexpressions constructed from the `ai___` won't be passed to the right-hand side, since there are no `ai` to pass them to. At the time when `otherLabels` is evaluated, this information is lost and only the symbols `ai` are returned.

A simple example of this issue is

```
labels = {a1, a2, a3};
rule = f[a1___, 1, a2___, 3, a3___] :> labels
(* f[a1___, 1, a2___, 3, a3___] :> labels *)

f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] /. rule
(* {a1, a2, a3} *)
```

**Solution**

A possible solution is to use `With` to make in the `RuleDelayed` a "literal" replacement of the symbol `otherLabels` with its value. For the example above, doing so, we have a renaming of the patterns:

```
rule2 = With[{temp = labels}, f[a1___, 1, a2___, 3, a3___] :> temp]
(* f[a1$___, 1, a2$___, 3, a3$___] :> {a1, a2, a3} *)
```

so it returns the same result:

```
f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] /. rule2
(* {a1, a2, a3} *)
```

Here are two possible work-arounds to get the renaming on the right-hand side as well:

*1)* Using the `With`-symbol to construct the pattern on the left-hand side:

```
rule2 = With[{temp = labels}, f @@ Riffle[(Pattern[#, ___] & /@ temp), {1, 3}] :> temp]
(* f[a1$___, 1, a2$___, 3, a3$___] :> {a1$, a2$, a3$} *)

f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] /. rule2
(* {2, 4, 5, 6} *)
```

*2)* Constructing the pattern in a `Module` and giving it to `RuleDelayed`:

```
rule2 = Module[{patt}, 
    patt = {a1___, 1, a2___, 3, a3___}; 
    With[{temp = labels}, f @@ patt :> temp]
]
(* f[a1$___, 1, a2$___, 3, a3$___] :> {a1$, a2$, a3$} *)

f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] /. rule2
(* {2, 4, 5, 6} *)
```

**Improving the code**

Since you do not need a `Block` or `Module`, we can use the first approach above, which gives for your code (`ReplaceRepeated` is replaced by `ReplaceAll` and I use `Unique` to create the symbols):

```
genSort2[expr_, lab_List] := expr /. 
   With[{temp = Table[Unique["a"], Length[lab] + 1]}, 

        {br @@ Riffle[Pattern[#, ___] & /@ temp, lab] :> 
           Signature[Riffle[temp, lab]] * Signature[Join[lab, temp]] * br @@ Join[lab, temp]
        }
   ];
```

Taking your example we get:

```
ex = br[1, 5, 7, 8, 9] br[3, 1, 5, 7, 8] br[3, 1, 4, 5] + 
     br[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5] br[1, 3, 5] br[1, 7, 8, 5, 3];

genSort2[ex, {1, 5}]
(* -br[1, 5, 3, 4] br[1, 5, 3, 7, 8] br[1, 5, 7, 8, 9] *)
```

We are missing the subexpression `br[1, 5, 3] br[1, 5, 7, 8, 3] br[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6]` in the result because the right-hand side is not yet correctly constructed. The last term of it gave `0` after applying the rule,

```
genSort2[br[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6], {1, 5}]
(* 0 *)
```

because `Riffle[{2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 5}]` gave `{2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6}` (the elements of the second list are used cyclically), and its `Signature` gave in turn `0`.

This will happen whenever the number of arguments of `br` is greater than `2 Length[lab] + 1`:

```
genSort2[br[2, 5, 1, 3], {1}]
(* 0 *)
```

Since `Signature` works on expression with heads different from `List`, you can simply take the expression that was matched by the pattern and passed it to the right-hand side of the rule.

**Final version**

Here is the final version of the code that keeps your initial idea:

```
genSort2[expr_, lab_List] := expr /. 
     With[{temp = Table[Unique["a"], Length[lab] + 1]}, 

          {lhs: br @@ Riffle[Pattern[#, ___] & /@ temp, lab] :> 
              Signature[lhs] * Signature[Join[lab, temp]] * br @@ Join[lab, temp]
          }
     ];
```

We get

```
genSort2[ex, {1, 5}]
(* -br[1, 5, 3, 4] br[1, 5, 3, 7, 8] br[1, 5, 7, 8, 9] + 
    br[1, 5, 3] br[1, 5, 7, 8, 3] br[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6] *)
```

which agrees with your `sort` function:

```
% === sort[ex, {1, 5}]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Xavier, for the very thorough answer. I will accept it over QuantumDot's solution, since it directly improves the idea in my code. Thanks for bringing up `Unique` and the `lhs : ...` construct, which I didn't know and found very interesting. :-)

Comment: I have a couple questions. 1) Why doesn't `Evaluate[rhs of the rule]` suffice to make my original code work? 2) How does `Signature[lhs]` not produce zero when riffling `lab` in the list of `a`'s? It seems equivalent to the previous code to me, but of course I am missing something!

Comment: @AndreaOrta 1) `Evaluate[rhs]` is going to evaluate the whole right-hand side expression before constructing the rule. For instance considering the subexpression `Signature[Join[lab, temp]]` (see final version from where it is extracted), the part `Join[lab, temp]` will be evaluated to produce, e.g., `{1, 2, a1, a2, a3}` (in the situation where `lab = {1, 2}`), and then `Signature[{1, 2, a1, a2, a3}]` will get evaluated to `1`. This last evaluation was done considering the *symbols* `ai`, and so is independent from their *values*, because this happened before the construction of the rule.

Comment: @AndreaOrta 2) a) In the old scenario (see the end of the part "Improving the code"), the riffling is done *after* the elements `ai` are replaced by their values given by the left-hand side, not *before*. Consider for instance `lab = {1}` and `br[1, 2, 3, 4]`. This last expression matches the pattern `br[a1___, 1, a2___]`, constructed from `br @@ Riffle[Pattern[#, ___] & /@ {a1, a2}, {1}]`, and you get the assignement `a1 = Sequence[]` and `a2 = Sequence[2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: @AndreaOrta 2) b) So `Riffle[{a1, a2}, {1}]` (corresponding to `Riffle[temp, lab]` in the right-hand side) becomes `Riffle[{2, 3, 4}, {1}]`, and gets evaluated to `{2, 1, 3, 1, 4}` (which has signature `0`). It is *not* evaluated to `{a1, 1, a2}` first and then replaced by `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help.  I would keep the arguments of `br` in canonical order, rather than trying to change the order manually.

This might be done by

```
unorderedq[_] := True
unorderedq[_?OrderedQ] := False

unorderedq[{1, 2}]
(* False *)

unorderedq[{2, 1}]
(* True *)

br[u__] /; unorderedq[{u}] := br @@ Sort[{u}] Signature[{u}]
```

Comment: A sight modification: `unorderedq[x_]:=!OrderedQ@x`

Comment: Excuse me, @mikado, I am not sure I am understanding your point. I really need to violate the canonical ordering of the arguments, for then applying some other function to them. However I agree that in principle it is better to impose a standard ordering and therefore I also have a `sorteverything` function, doing what yours does. Is this what you wanted to point out?